# User reports they can't download APK

Tags: android

I am sharing my APK with the entire world but it throws this error to a user:

```
Sorry! This content is not available in your country yet.
We're working to bring the content you love to more countries as quickly as possible.
Please check back again soon.
```

Comment: In the `Pricing and Distribution` page of your console, you can manage the countries in which your app is distributed to. Please refer to my answer for screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage your app's list of targeted countries here.

[image]

Comment: It says the same number of countries that are available.

Comment: Did you just published it not long ago? I understand that it takes awhile for the app to be available in the Play Store. In my country itself, it would take about 6 hours before it is available. So it might be the case that it's still being processed for other countries' play store.

Comment: Its been available for over a week

Comment: Perhaps you would wish to try asking it here http://android.stackexchange.com/, you may get more help from there.